# How can I pass input to a function, then have it use that input across 5 internal functions that are chaining each other?

Tags: python, function, input, arguments, chaining

This is essentially 2 questions I think.

1. How do I make all internal functions use the same raw_input?
2. How do I chain functions with that input?

I've been trying to make something that will make a circle shape with whatever character the user inputs. (This is a "for fun" activity that I thought up to help me get used to functions. I've only been self teaching Python for 2 weeks now)
So far my code is:

```
def circle(symbol):

    def lines1(aa):
        print(symbol * 20)
        aa()
        print(symbol * 20)
    return(lines1)

    def lines2(bb):
        print(symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + symbol * 7)
        bb()
        print(symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + symbol * 7)
    return(lines2)

    def lines3(cc):
        print(symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + symbol * 4)
        cc()
        print(symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + symbol * 4)
    return(lines3)

    def lines4(dd):
        print(symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + symbol * 2)
        dd()
        print(symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + symbol * 2)
    return(lines4)

    def lines5():
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)
    return(lines5)

    lines1(lines2(lines3(lines4(lines5()))))

circle(raw_input())
```

Example: If the user inputs a #, it is supposed to output:

```
####################
#######      #######
####            ####
##                ##
#                  #
#                  #
##                ##
####            ####
#######      #######
####################
```

The problem is it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Your `return` statements are *outside* of your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cicles` function returns early:

```
def circle(symbol):

    def lines1(aa):
        print(symbol * 20)
        aa()
        print(symbol * 20)
    return(lines1)
```

The rest of your function is *not* executed.

Next, you use functions that want to call other functions, but you never pass in the arguments. `aa()` is not given any reference to the `lines2()` function.

Instead, you call `lines5()`, which returns `None`, then pass that to `lines4()`, which cannot call `lines4()`.

You'll need inner wrappers to make this work the way you want to:

```
def circle(symbol):

    def lines1(inner):
        def wrapper():
            print(symbol * 20)
            inner()
            print(symbol * 20)
        return wrapper

    def lines2(inner):
        def wrapper():
            print(symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + symbol * 7)
            inner()
            print(symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + symbol * 7)
        return wrapper

    def lines3(inner):
        def wrapper():
            print(symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + symbol * 4)
            inner()
            print(symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + symbol * 4)
        return wrapper

    def lines4(inner):
        def wrapper():
            print(symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + symbol * 2)
            inner()
            print(symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + symbol * 2)
        return wrapper

    def lines5():
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)

    lines1(lines2(lines3(lines4(lines5))))()
```

Now functions `lines1` through `lines4` each return a wrapper function to be passed into the next function, effectively making them decorators. We start with `lines5` (as a function reference, *not by calling it* then call the result of the nested wrappers.

The definition of `lines5` could now also use `@decorator` syntax:

```
    @lines1
    @lines2
    @lines3
    @lines4
    def lines5():
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)

    line5()
```

Comment: I thought lines1(lines2(lines3(lines4(lines5())))) was passing in the next decorator as its argument, thus creating a chain down to lines5?

Comment: @JosephWebber: The **inner-most** function is executed first, so `lines5()` is executed, then it's return value is passed to `lines4()`, which is executed, etc.

Comment: @JosephWebber: In my version, `lines5` is **not** executed. `lines4()` then executes, this time with `lines5` as an argument. It returns `wrapper`, another function. This is passed to `lines3()`, etc., until `lines1()` returns a wrapper function. **Then** we call that last return value.

Comment: @JosephWebber: The `wrapper` from `lines1` then executes, prints a line and calls the `wrapper` returned by `lines2`; it prints a line, calls he `wrapper` from `lines3`, etc. all the way until `lines5` is called and returns. Then the other `print` lines are executed in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but I just have one more question.
Where is it appropriate/not appropriate to call a decorator?

Comment: @JosephWebber: anything that can be used with the `@decorator` syntax . Function decorators must return a callable, class decorators a class. That's about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your not using decorators,

To make your code work as is:

```
class circle(object):

    def __init__(self, symbol):    
        self.symbol = symbol

    def lines1(self):
        print(self.symbol * 20)
        print(self.symbol * 20)

    def lines2(self):
        print(self.symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + self.symbol * 7)
        print(self.symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + self.symbol * 7)


    def lines3(self):
        print(self.symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + self.symbol * 4)
        print(self.symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + self.symbol * 4)

    def lines4(self):
        print(self.symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + self.symbol * 2)
        print(self.symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + self.symbol * 2)

    def lines5(self):
        print(self.symbol + ' ' * 18 + self.symbol)
        print(self.symbol + ' ' * 18 + self.symbol)

    def print_circle(self):
        self.lines1()
        self.lines2()
        self.lines3()
        self.lines4()
        self.lines5()
        self.lines4()
        self.lines3()
        self.lines2()
        self.lines1()

x = circle(raw_input())
x.print_circle()
```

Check out this question on decorators I found it too be very helpful in the past:
[How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

Comment: I've been looking at that page myself, but it doesn't say anything about using raw_input among them all.

Comment: No problem, if you want us to add something more to the answer just leave us a comment

Comment: raw_input just takes an input, it of it self has nothing to do with decorators.

Answer (score 0):

So much duplication there, and here is my functional style solution:

```
def cycle(s):
    def lines1(symbol):
        print(symbol * 20)

    def lines2(symbol):
        print(symbol * 7 + ' ' * 6 + symbol * 7)

    def lines3(symbol):
        print(symbol * 4 + ' ' * 12 + symbol * 4)

    def lines4(symbol):
        print(symbol * 2 + ' ' * 16 + symbol * 2)

    def lines5(symbol):
        print(symbol + ' ' * 18 + symbol)

    def combine(F, *FS):
        if not FS: return F
        fn, rest = FS[0], FS[1:]
        def wrapper(s):
            fn(s)
            F(s)
            fn(s)
        return combine(wrapper, *rest)

    return combine(lines5, lines4, lines3, lines2, lines1)(s)

cycle(raw_input())
```